# How to copy "shape.table" object extract from PPT to word with formatting?

Tags: python

I want copy table form PPTX and copy to word with same format.

I already extract table from PPTX as a `table = shape.table`  object . But I can't copy this table in word.

```py
prs = Presentation(pptx_filename)
slide = prs.slides[5]
for shape in slide.shaslide:
    if not shape.has_table:
        continue
    table = shape.table

paragraph = document.add_table(table)
```

`paragraph = document.add_table(table)`  this is will not working.

Comment: Please explain how it isn't working (error messages, etc.).

Comment: add_table(table) missing 1 required positional argument: 'cols'  should be indect

Comment: I think add table is not correct function for "shape.table" object . but document is no add_shape function .